# Rewrite htaccess from specific subfolder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a htaccess setting which ***already*** rewrite all request to index.php . but now i am having a condition where i want to rewrite (i am not sure how to do or which to choose) **a subfolder /admin to index.php?route=admin/login** , yes with the exact url

***Expectation***

> www.domain.com/admin
>
> rewrite to
>
> www.domain.com/index.php?route=admin/login

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/install(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
#########################################

##I expect the line below will go to the url , but when i enter the subfolder , the page remain at the index
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /$1?route=admin/login [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in `/admin/` folder?

Comment: @anubhava Yes , i can have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing this in `/admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?route=admin/login [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite to admin login from www.domain.com/admin

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ /index.php?route=admin/login [R=301,L]
```

Rewrite other requests, example:

www.domain.com/admin/list_users

www.domain.com/admin/send_mail

etc.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /index.php?route=admin/$1 [R=301,L]
```

UPD.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/install(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
#########################################

##I expect the line below will go to the url , but when i enter the subfolder , the page remain at the index
#RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /$1?route=admin/login [R=301,L]
```

AND from php file instead $_GET['route'] use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

OR UPD domain.com/admin/login

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /index.php?route=admin/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/install(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
#########################################
```

Comment: U have RewriteRule . index.php [L]/

Comment: Read my question carefully

Comment: its still the same , should i go for redirect?

Comment: "redirect" is to send to a different domain (R=302 is default, R=301 can be given explicitly). Actually, any giving of http: and the domain is a redirect, even if it's to the same domain. "rewrite" is staying within the current domain by not giving http: and domain (R=200 is the default).